# Ordering Strings in Prolog

Tags: string, prolog, sql-order-by

I want to know how can I compare two strings that would tell me if one string is greater that the other one, or not.

I don't want equality/inequality. I want to have the good old alphanumeric ordering.

Example:
'aaaa' ,'aaad', 'aaab'
the sorted should be:
'aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaad'

Also, what if I have atoms? How to order atoms? (again a=b or a\=b doesn't do the job, i need order.)

Answer (score 8):

Use the term-ordering predicates `@<` and friends.

```
?- aaaa @< aaab.
true.

?- aaad @>= aaab.
true.
```